# Stuck at Vagrant connect to SSH

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, virtualbox, vagrant

I am using Vagrant 2.3.4 and Virtual Box 7.0.8 to setup VM box eurolinux-vagrant/centos-stream-9 9.0.37 on Windows 10.

After using `vagrant up`, I have faced the SSH issue with this log:

```
Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["D:\\Virtual Box\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
DEBUG virtualbox_7_0: Searching for SSH port: 22
DEBUG virtualbox_7_0: read_forward_ports: uuid=6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f active_only=false
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["D:\\Virtual Box\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
DEBUG virtualbox_7_0:   - [1, "ssh", 2200, 22, "127.0.0.1"]
 INFO ssh: Attempting SSH connection...
 INFO ssh: Attempting to connect to SSH...
 INFO ssh:   - Host: 127.0.0.1
 INFO ssh:   - Port: 2200
 INFO ssh:   - Username: vagrant
 INFO ssh:   - Password? false
 INFO ssh:   - Key Path: ["C:/Users/ADMIN/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"]
DEBUG ssh:   - connect_opts: {:auth_methods=>["none", "hostbased", "publickey"], :config=>false, :forward_agent=>false, :send_env=>false, :keys_only=>true, :verify_host_key=>:never, :password=>nil, :port=>2200, :timeout=>15, :user_known_hosts_file=>[], :verbose=>:debug, :logger=>#<Logger:0x00000261b8144e68 @level=0, @progname=nil, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x00000261b8144e40 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=nil, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x00000261b8144df0 @shift_period_suffix=nil, @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<StringIO:0x00000261b8144eb8>, @binmode=false, @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x00000261b8144dc8>, @mon_data_owner_object_id=184780>>, :keys=>["C:/Users/ADMIN/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"], :remote_user=>"vagrant"}
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["D:\\Virtual Box\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["D:\\Virtual Box\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["D:\\Virtual Box\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["D:\\Virtual Box\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["D:\\Virtual Box\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["D:\\Virtual Box\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["D:\\Virtual Box\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["D:\\Virtual Box\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["D:\\Virtual Box\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["D:\\Virtual Box\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["D:\\Virtual Box\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["D:\\Virtual Box\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "6ac2bff0-d050-49b1-a801-a426ffa39c9f", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
DEBUG ssh: == Net-SSH connection debug-level log START ==
DEBUG ssh: D, [2023-12-16T22:25:27.621115 #18544] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[2d1e0]: establishing connection to 127.0.0.1:2200

DEBUG ssh: == Net-SSH connection debug-level log END ==
ERROR warden: Error occurred: Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.
```

I tried uninstalling vagrant and virtualbox software or using "vagrant up" after using "vagrant destroy" but they do not work. I even searched solutions for this but nothing works. Please help me, i'm stucked at there over 3-4 days :<. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.